# Can anybody explain to me how to solve such questions? Constellation Diagram

Tags: digital-communications

[image: problem]

i'm not able to proceed with such questions. If someone could explain how to solve such questions, would be a big help. Thanks.

Comment: this requires thinking as vectors, and finding the energy in a vector

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework question with no attempt at an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General procedure to compute this is listed here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/53451/20390 .  You need to compute the amplitude of each point, convert those to power, and then perform a weighted average.  Looks like you'll have to do some basic geometry to figure out the amplitudes, which would be the distance from the origin to each point.